# How do i check if theres 2 substring in a string?

Tags: c++, find, substring

I want to check if 2 substrings in a string exist
like for example:

```cpp
string main_string = 'Hello "sir"';
```

I want to check if that string included 2 `"`,must included 2.
And also I want to check this:

```cpp
string main_string = 'Bruh (moment)';
```

I want to check if that string included both `(` and `)`.

Comment: String literals in C++ are delimited by double-quotes (`"..."`), not by single-quotes (`'...'`), eg: `string main_string = "Bruh (moment)";` If you need to include double-quotes inside the string, you have to escape them with ```\```, eg: `string main_string = "Hello \"sir\"";`

Comment: Hi, many users, including me, feel with you. Explaining downvotes is encouraged but disappointingly rarely done. However, you seem to have missed an intentional design decision: https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote I.e. StackOverflow WANTS votes (up and down) and decided to protect voters from retaliation, by allowing anonymous voting. So users who vote anonymously are doing as allowed and appreciated, though doing it with explanation to help with improving would of course be even more appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases, you can use [`std::string::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

```cpp
std::string main_string = "Hello \"sir\"";
std::size_t pos = main_string.find('"');
if (pos != std::string::npos)
{
    pos = main_string.find('"', pos+1);
    if (pos != std::string::npos)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

```cpp
std::string main_string = "Bruh (moment)";
std::size_t pos = main_string.find('(');
if (pos != std::string::npos)
{
    pos = main_string.find(')', pos+1);
    if (pos != std::string::npos)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

In the first case, you can alternatively use [`std::count()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) instead.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
std::string main_string = "Hello \"sir\"";
std::size_t cnt = std::count(main_string.begin(), main_string.end(), '"');
if (cnt == 2)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: What about the performance? I think one loop is enough but when use STL we seem to loop twice.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin if your use of the STL is causing multiple loops then you are likely using it wrong